# Proof that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$ using just the algebraic properties of $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, real-numbers, axioms

Like the title says, can you prove rigorously that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$ using only the nine field properties of $\mathbb R$? I don't know if addition and multiplication are supposed to be pre-defined, for instance, if $+$ says that $5 + 6 = 11$ automatically without any proof. This is true in common sense math, but the question I'm really wanting to know is are equations like those all just derived solely from those nine algebraic field properties of $\mathbb R$?

Like it seems obvious that $5\cdot0 = 0$, but that's because $0 =5\cdot 0 - 5\cdot0= 5\cdot(0+0)-5\cdot0 = (5\cdot0 + 5\cdot0)-5\cdot0$

$=5\cdot0 + (5\cdot0 - 5\cdot0)=5\cdot0+0=5\cdot0$, using additive identities, additive inverses, distributive laws, and additive associativity. Can a similar proof be formed for $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2} (1+1)=\frac{1}{2}\times 2 = 1.$

Comment: Is there a proof that $1+1=2$?

Comment: The definition of $2$ is $1 + 1$. (I hope nobody mentions Principia Mathematica...)

Comment: @littleO: Too late, you already mentioned it. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

\begin{align}
& \frac12 \cdot 2 = 1 \qquad \qquad\text{(definition of $\frac12$)} \\
\implies& \frac12 \cdot (1 + 1) = 1 \qquad\qquad  \text{(definition of $2$)} \\
\implies& \frac12 \cdot 1 + \frac12 \cdot 1 = 1 \qquad \qquad \text{(distributive property)} \\
\implies& 
\frac12 + \frac12 = 1 \qquad \text{(because $1$ is a multiplicative identity)}.
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't know that the number 2 was already defined. Please explain, because I didn't see that anywhere in the axioms.

Comment: In my mind, the definition of $2$ is $1 + 1$. If you're using a different definition of $2$, then we'll need a different proof. Presumably the number $2$ has been defined somehow before this theorem has been stated.

Answer (score 4):

As already said by others, $1/2 +1/2=1$ is basically the definition of $1/2$ as the inverse of the number $2$ which, in $\mathbb R$, is a synonym of $1+1$.

But No, you cannot prove that by using only the "nine properties of fields". This is because you cannot prove that $1+1$ is invertible.

In fact there exist fields where $1+1=0$. For example $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ Is a field, it has only two elements: $0,1$ and there $1+1=0$.

Comment: @mrtaurho no, using the axiom of fields you cannot prove that $1+1\neq0$. Your argument uses that $-1\neq1$, which in fact is equivalent to $1+1\neq0$.  In $\mathbb R$ this is true because you have more axioms than just those of fields. For instance you have order (with order you can prove that if $x\neq0$ then $x+x\neq 0$) that in other fields is missing.